# Subwords of a fibonacci word

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, fibonacci

I'm trying to understand this:

http://tcs.uj.edu.pl/~walczak/fibonacci.pdf

I have a word created from a concatenation of a couple of =Fibonacci words=,
and I need to check, is this word is a subword of another larger fib. word.

Example:

```
S0    0
S1    01
S2    010
S3    01001
S4    01001010
S5    0100101001001
```

...

input -> subword is : S2 + S1 + S1 = 0100101

output: true, because S2+S1+S1 is a subword of S4

0100101 (subword)

01001010 (S4)

---

Please I have problems to understand English, maybe if you can, please
write some code in java/c# or delphi.

Even a sample of code, maybe I understand a bit more.

Comment: We can't write code for you. What have you tried?

Comment: please write code of the function, whats is example?

Comment: Damn you guys, I'm trying to solve it 2 days... I'm looking someone here who knows the problem, i dont ask you for waste your time for me. In PDF file there are 3 pseudo code, but I cant understand them...

Comment: You should give us some initial code snippet or ideas and info what exactly you don't understand. Also, you have a few questions here on stackoverflow, but you don't accept any answers as correct or being helpful for you to get to the solution. People will be discouraged to help you if you provide no feedback ...

Comment: It's his task :/ Darjan: I didn't accept answers? Well where? Im always clicki UP arrow for helpful answers.

Comment: It's the green tick you need to put to the best answer (but only if it is helpful of course)

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong tree, even if some people here can process that notation into code (which I'm sure some can), it won't help you understand it particularly well.  Try this site, it has similar questions and they'll help you break down the math. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60514/subwords-of-the-fibonacci-word

Comment: Darjan: OK i found it, ty. w00te, Ty, i lost link to this stackoverflow question, now i will read this carefuly.

Comment: mathoverflow* :) thats why i coundt fin it again hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if performance is no issue:

you can run digit digit comparison using the direct formula:

f(n) =
[image: formula]

where **φ** is the golden ratio.
and **n** denotes the n-th digit.

```
//w denotes lookup word
isSubWord(w){
  i=0;
  cnt=0;
  while(i!=w.length){
    if(f(i+cnt)==w(cnt)){
      ++cnt;
    }else{
      cnt=0;
      ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude, thank you. But I already know this. The problem is that lenght can be fib(1000000000) as max, so this algorithm is useful for small words. I need to use tricks from PDF file that i linked, but description inside this file is too hard for understand for me :/

Comment: if its the math inside you find trouble with try posting same question in mathoverflow http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60514/subwords-of-the-fibonacci-word